# Why does the vale of jaunts (specifically the 1st value) change when I'm not updating jaunts at all? I'm just updating the 'o'

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement, assignment-operator

```
start = [2020,0,0,2020]
jaunts = [[2020,0,0,2021],[2021,0,0,2022],[2022,0,0,2023],[2020,1,1,2023],[2021,0,0,2023]]

def gridneighbors(start,jaunts):
    neigh = []
    for o in jaunts:
        new_cell = o
        if start[0]==o[0] and (start[1] == o[1] and start[2] == o[2]):
            new_cell[0]=o[3]
            neigh.append(o)
        elif start[3]==o[3] and (start[1] == o[1] and start[2] == o[2]):
            o[3]=o[0]
            neigh.append(o)
        print(jaunts)
    return neigh

print(gridneighbors(start,jaunts))

output:
[[2021, 0, 0, 2021], [2021, 0, 0, 2022], [2022, 0, 0, 2023], [2020, 1, 1, 2023], [2021, 0, 
0, 2023]]
```

This is the value of jaunts im getting, the 1st value has changed when ive not even updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you assign to a variable another variable that is a list you are actually creating a new reference to the same list so when you change something in the second variable you are changing also in the first variable because both represent the same list, ex:

```
first_list = [2020, 0,0, 2021]
second_list = first_list

second_list[0] = first_list[3]
print(first_list)
```

output:

```
[2021, 0, 0, 2021]
```

the same thing it is happening in your for loop in the first iteration, your `new_cell` and `o` variables are actually both the same `jaunted[0]`; when you are doing `new_cell[0]=o[3]` you are doing: `jaunted[0][0] = jaunted[0][3]`

Comment: use copies: `o = o.copy()`